# How do I write encoded information (JPEG/JFIF) when it is not a multiple of eight?

Tags: compression, jpeg

I'm trying to write a baseline JPEG encoder. I already know how the handle the [JFIF format](http://www.videotechnology.com/jpeg/j1.html) (very good article, BTW). Right now I'm trying to compress a 8x8 grayscale image that is basically white. So, considering that a white pixel is basically 255, [once you apply the JPEG algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_codec_example) (obviating the zig zag step, because for this example it is basically unnecessary) you get this matrix:

```
B = [63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

As we can see, there's only one DC component (63) and no AC components. [If you check the Huffman tables](http://www.globalspec.com/reference/39556/203279/appendix-b-huffman-tables-for-the-dc-and-ac-coefficients-of-the-jpeg-baseline-encoder) you find that the category is 6 (**1110**) and because 63 in binary is  111111 the sequence of bits for this DC component is 1110111111 (10 bits). Now, according to the algorithm, when all AC components are 0 you need to send EOB, whose sequence is 1010 (four bits). So, in the end, the final sequence of bits is **11101111111010** (14 bits).

Now, we already know that I can only write (or append) bytes to a file. So I am trying to write something like this to a new .jpeg file:

```
0xFF 0xD8 .. JFIF metadata ... 11101111111010 0xFF 0xD9
SOI marker                     block          EOI marker
```

The question is, what should I do about those 14 bits? I guess I need to insert 2 filler bits (I don't know if there's a better term for them) to get 2 bytes but I don't know where to insert them, let alone their values (00? 01? 10? 11?). I suppose that this is a common problem in data encoding and/or low-level programming so I it is widely solved :)

Comment: I don't know what the spec says, but I think if you pad with 0 bits to get to a byte boundary you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JPEG format](http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~mmanowie/psap/neue/1%20JPEG%20Overview.htm) says that:

> The only padding that occurs is at the end of the scan when the remaining bits in the last byte to be filled with 1’s if the byte is incomplete.

So you are supposed to fill with `1`-s here. That means in fine you should have:

```
1110       111111            1010         11
DC code    DC value (=63)    EOB (=10)    Extra 1-s
```

In other words `11101111 11101011` which gives the `0xEF 0xEB` sequence in hexadecimal.

Pro-tip: you can refer to this [code section](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec/blob/8c422c545262f60b53e8e73da755a1dc7bde3766/src/huff.c#L68) from [jpec](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec) - a tiny JPEG encoder written in C. Also, the [`jpec_huff_write_bits`](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec/blob/8c422c545262f60b53e8e73da755a1dc7bde3766/src/huff.c#L133) includes a relevant documentation that may help you understand how to write the bits at Huffman time.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that. The encoder is working very well right now.